# Combine multiple excel workbooks into one master workbook

Tags: excel, vba

As mentioned above in the title. I have been looking out for ways. 
I have tried the method of using VB scripting to combine excel workbooks into one excel workbook. However, while i was doing the scripting, there was no sign of the compilation of all the workbook into the master workbook.

Here is my VB script that i've done:

```
Sub GetSheets()
Path = "C:\Users\..."
Filename = Dir(Path & ".xlsx") 
Do While Filename <> ""
Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
Sheet.Copy After:=This.Workbook.Sheets(1)
Next Sheet 
Workbooks(Filename).Close
Filename = Dir()
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: You may find this helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30605765/4961700

Comment: Tried. It gives me a new excel workbook instead of compiling my files together.

Comment: So, what is wrong with combining all the files into a new workbook - that does seem to be what you want... Edit the code to make it do what you need - that is what I did...

Answer (score 0):

When you open a workbook, it becomes the active workbook.

```
Sub GetSheets()

    Path = "C:\Users\..."
    Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx")
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim Wb0 As Workbook: Set Wb0 = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim Sh As Worksheet

    Do While Filename <> ""
        Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(Path & Filename)

        For Each Sh In Wb.Sheets
            Sh.Copy After:=Wb0.Sheets(Wb0.Sheets.Count)
        Next Sh

        Wb.Saved = True
        Wb.Close
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Joe, i've also tried using your code, but there's still no sign of compilation of worksheets in the master workbook.

Comment: Change `Filename = Dir(Path & ".xlsx")` to `Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx")` and make sure your path ends with "\"