# Efficiently import multiple spreadsheets into one master sheet using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and I have some code which I have written and although it works I think it is bulky and not very good should a change ever need to be made to it.

The code opens a spreadsheet, runs a Function (Called "LastRow") to copy the data and another (Called "NxtRow")to paste it into the next empty row of the spreadsheet with the macro then closes the sheet that the data was copied from and moves on to the next one. Basically it is concatenating multiple sheets into one.

I am thinking that there must be a way to write the code to call the functions once and then loop through each sheet in a list. Is this possible?

My code is:

NxtRow() Function

```
Public Function NxtRow()
Dim BlankRow As Long
Windows("GA_BudgetTool_MASTER.xlsm").Activate
BlankRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Cells(BlankRow, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
BlankRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Cells(BlankRow, 1).Select
End Function
```

LstRow() Function

```
Public Function LastRow()
Dim LstRow As Long, LstCol As Long, Rng As Range, A3 As Range
LstRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LstCol = Range("O" & LstRow).Column
Set Rng = Range(Cells(LstRow, 1), Cells(LstRow, LstCol))
Set A3 = Range("A3")
Range(A3, Rng).Select
Selection.Copy
End Function
```

VBA Sub()

```
Sub ImpData()

'   Deactivate Screen Updating and Display Alerts
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'   Import Worksheet 1
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
"Worksheet1_Filename.xlsx"
LastRow
NxtRow
Windows("Worksheet1.xlsx").Activate
ActiveWindow.Close

'   Import Worksheet 2
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
"Worksheet2_Filename.xlsx"
LastRow
NxtRow
Windows("Worksheet2.xlsx").Activate
ActiveWindow.Close

'   Import Worksheet 3
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
"Worksheet3_Filename.xlsx"
LastRow
NxtRow
Windows("Worksheet3.xlsx").Activate
ActiveWindow.Close
```

This goes on in this fashion for about 30 sheets. Is there an easier way to write this and make it easier to amend later if needed?

Comment: well, you could look at what I finally ended up with in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30605765 if it helps give it a vote!

Comment: Are they actually named with the "1", "2", etc in their names or is that generic so that you can post it here?

Comment: Also, could you post lastrow and nextrow so that we can make changes to them? you're relying too much on `activate` and `select`

Comment: @ Marcucciboy No the names given are have had to be changed for Data Protection reasons

Comment: Check out the new PowerQuery functionality in Excel...perfect for this kind of challenge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just make a little array of your filenames and then use a for loop to repeat the function calls as many times as necessary

```
Sub ImpData()

    'Deactivate Screen Updating and Display Alerts
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    Dim filenames As Variant
    filenames = Array("file1", "file2")

    For i = 1 To UBound(filenames) + 1
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=filenames(i - 1)
        LastRow
        NxtRow
        Windows("Worksheet" & i & ".xlsx").Activate
        ActiveWindow.Close
    Next i

    'Reactivate Screen Updating and Display Alerts
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you for your help!

Comment: @FirepowerG Glad it helped! Please consider clicking the checkbox to accept it as the best answer :)