# Excel VBA: Loop through sheets / transfer data / create new workbook for each

Tags: vba, excel

could you please help me out adjusting my macro?

#### What I have

- Selecting different workbooks(`wb1,wb2..`.) via a file explorer dialog
  window and listing them in a listbox
- Transfering certain data from the selected workbooks to a workbook
  template(`wb_template`) and saving it as a `new workbook`.
- The `new workbook` contains the data from `wb_1`, but the structure of
  `wb_template` The User Form Looks like this:
  [image]

#### What I need

I need to adjust the way the relevant data from the workbooks is selected("Transfer-data" button). I would need a `loop` which is going through every sheet of `wb_1` and is covering the following:

- Look for certain terms in `wb_1` and move/rename them to `wb_template` in specific sheet/column/cell.
  **Example:** [image]
- Look for certain terms in `wb_1` and just take the value, which is stored in the cell on the right side of it, and move to `wb_template` in specific sheet/column/cell.
  **Example**: [image]

The steps above should be applied to every sheet of `wb_1` and for every sheet should be a `new workbook` created.

So, at the end of the process **I should have a `new workbook` for every sheet in `wb_1`.**
**For example**: if `wb_1` has 5 sheets, there should be 5 `new workbooks` created (`wb1_1, wb1_2, wb1_3,...`).

​
**Here is a simple overview visual showing what I exactly want to achieve with this macro:**

[image]

#### My actual code

**Transfer Data Button**

```
Sub Transferfile(wbTempPath As String, wbTargetPath As String)
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb_template As Workbook

    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(wbTargetPath)
    Set wb_template = Workbooks.Open(wbTempPath)

    '/* Definition of the value range */
    wb_template.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value
    wb_template.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Value = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Value
    wb_template.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value
    wb_template.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Value = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Value

    wb1Name = Left(wb1.Name, InStr(wb1.Name, ".") - 1)
    wb_template.SaveAs wb1.Path & "\" & wb1Name & "_New.xlsx"
    wb1.Close False
    wb_template.Close False
End Sub
```

**Browse File Button** - I guess not so relevant for this topic

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim fNames As Variant

    With Me
        fNames = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel File(s) (*.xls*),*.xls*", , , , True)
        If IsArray(fNames) Then .ListBox1.List = fNames
    End With
End Sub

​
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim i As Integer

    '/* full path to the template file */
    Const mytemplate As String = "C:\Users\PlutoX\Desktop\Excel-Folder\wb_template.xlsx"

    With Me
        With .ListBox1
            '/* iterate listbox items */
            For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
                '/* transfer the files using the generic procedure */
                Transferfile mytemplate, .List(i, 0)
            Next
        End With
    End With
End Sub​
```

Thanks for the help!

**Summary**:

I need to search for for specific keywords in a sheet of wb1.

I dont know the positions of those keywords

In case a keyword is found - condition1 or condition2 will be applied, depending on the keyword:

- **Condition 1**: if keyword in wb1 = "House_1" then copy/paste keyword in wb2 (specific position -> Sheet2, A3) and rename it to
  "House Blue".Result would be: "House Blue" in A3 of Sheet2 in wb2.
- **Condition 2**: if keyword in wb1 = "Number" then copy the value of the adjoining cell to the right of it and paste in wb2 (specific
  position -> Sheet3, C5).Result would be: "4" in C5 of Sheet3 in wb2.

So what I want to do is to determine the relevant keywords - and which condition the respective keyword is triggering.

**Update:**

I dont know the specific sheet, so every sheet in the wb should be checked

Actually, my goal is to have a set of keywords, which have condition 1 or condition 2 assigned, as well as a specific paste-location in wb_template. So, every sheet should be checked according to the set of keywords. A keyword can only have one of the conditions assigned.

Comment: Have a look at this - it may help : https://stackoverflow.com/q/30575923/4961700

Comment: You described quite well what you need. But I'm not sure about where you got stuck exactly? Is it just that you need to wrap your code in `Transferfile` into a loop that loops through all the sheets?

Comment: Your question is too unspecific. Are there only these 2 keywords (`House_1`, `Number`)  and only these 2 conditions? And are the locations/addresses fixed?

Comment: Hi, see update above.There are just those two conditions. But there will be a set of different keywords. The location in w1 is not fixed. The location those keywords are pasted to is fixed - so every keyword has a fixed "paste to" location in wb_template.

Comment: Some clarification is needed: 

How do you define what your keywords are and their respective definitions? Are they listed somewhere?

Would you define these in your code?

Would these be searched for on every sheet of your original file?

What range would be used for the target if the keyword/condition was found/met? Is it similar to where it was found in the source sheet?

Answer (score 1):

If the challenge you are facing is to find a specific word ***which could be lying anywhere in the workbook*** you can make use of Excel's inbuilt function *"Find"* with slight modification.

I will post a sample snippet which does the same. Please modify it accordingly.

Code Snippet: [ Tried & tested ]

```
Sub FindMyWord()

Dim sht As Worksheet  
For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets     'Change workbook object accordingly  

Dim CellWhereWordIs As Range
Set CellWhereWordIs = sht.Cells.Find("Charlie", LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
                                    'Charlie is the word I wanna find. Change parmeters accordingly  

    If Not CellWhereWordIs Is Nothing Then
    
         'Do something here
          MsgBox "Word found in: " & sht.Name & "/" & CellWhereWordIs.Address
    
    Else
    
          MsgBox "Word not found in " & sht.Name, vbExclamation

    End If  

Next  

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to wrap your code into a loop going through all the worksheets.

I also recommend to use a bit more descriptive variable names: `wb1` is not very descriptive but if you change it to `wbSource` it is very clear that this is the workbook  where the data comes from.

Finally I recommend to use `Application.PathSeparator` instead of `"\"` to make it independent form your operating system (eg. MacOS uses `"/"` instead of `"\"`).

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TransferFile(TemplateFile As String, SourceFile As String)
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(SourceFile) 'open source

    Dim wbTemplate As Workbook
    Dim NewWbName As String

    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    For Each wsSource In wbSource.Worksheets 'loop through all worksheets in source workbook
        Set wbTemplate = Workbooks.Open(TemplateFile) 'open new template

        '/* Definition of the value range */
        With wbTemplate.Worksheets("Sheet1")
            .Range("A2").Value = wsSource.Range("A2").Value
            .Range("A3").Value = wsSource.Range("A3").Value
            .Range("B2").Value = wsSource.Range("B2").Value
            .Range("B3").Value = wsSource.Range("B3").Value
        End With

        NewWbName = Left(wbSource.Name, InStr(wbSource.Name, ".") - 1)
        wbTemplate.SaveAs wbSource.Path & Application.PathSeparator & NewWbName & "_New.xlsx"
        wbTemplate.Close False 'close template
    Next wsSource

    wbSource.Close False 'close source
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your feedback! Now I got an idea how to loop through the sheets. However, my initial problem/question still prevails - I dont know how to redefine the "value range" in my code.... As of now the range is fixed, but I need it to be like explained in point 1 and 2 of "what I need". The code has to search for certain keyowrds/terms in wb_1 before transfering the data to the wb_template. I'm not sure how to do this...

Comment: To find a specific keyword have a look at the [Range.Find Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Find) or the [WorksheetFunction.VLookup Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.WorksheetFunction.VLookup). Then you can use the [Range.Offset Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset) to move relatively from the found cell.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm still not sure how to implement the conditions according to the methods..? I've updated my post with a "Summary" for a better understanding.