# Moving Worsksheet after a Named Worksheet in Excel using pywin32 Dispatch

Tags: python, excel, pywin32

I have tons of files where I need to copy a certain sheet from them to another workbook, they need to be placed after a sheet with a specific name, while keeping all the formatting in the sheet that is being moved.

I saw in another thread that pywin32 would be the way to go, however I am having a hard time with copying this sheet "After" the named sheet.

```
xl = Dispatch("Excel.Application")

xl.Visible = True  
xl.AskToUpdateLinks = False
xl.EnableEvents = False
xl.DisplayAlerts = False

wb1 = xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename=p1)
wb2 = xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename=p2)    
ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("ThisSheet")

##PROBLEM LINE HERE
ws1.Copy(After=wb2.Worksheets("AfterThisSheet"))
##END OF PROBLEM LINE

wb2.Sheets("ThisSheet").Name = "NewNameInNewWorkBook"
wb2.Close(SaveChanges=True)
wb1.Close(SaveChanges=True)

xl.Quit()
```

When I use "Before" instead of "After", this operation is done successfully but unfortunately the sheet I want to copy ends in the wrong place.

When I use "After" it throws back an error.

I can use other packages in python like pandas, xlrd etc. but then, they seem to have issues with keeping the formatting intact.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: As you tagged excel, then here is some vba code I use for something similar : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30605765

Answer (score 2):

The solution turned out to be simple actually, it seems that the Copy method required both a specification for "Before" and "After"

```
##PROBLEM LINE HERE
ws1.Copy(After=wb2.Worksheets("AfterThisSheet"))
##END OF PROBLEM LINE

##CORRECT STATEMENT
ws1.Copy(None, After=wb2.Worksheets("AfterThisSheet"))
##END OF CORRECT STATEMENT
```

So "None" should be passed to the "Before" parameter, before specifying After.