# Move worksheet within a workbook to the end

Tags: python, excel, pywin32, xlwings

With xlwings, I am trying to move a worksheet within a workbook to the end. For example, a workbook contains a collection of the following sheets:
`Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3`

How can I move Sheet1 after Sheet3 in order to get the following order? 
`Sheet2, Sheet3, Sheet1`

If I use `ws1.api.Move(Before=ws3.api)` with the `Before` parameter the line works as expected, but it doesn't with the [`After`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.move#parameters) parameter. See example code:

```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book("test.xlsx")

ws1 = wb.sheets['Sheet1']
ws3 = wb.sheets['Sheet3']

ws1.api.Move(After=ws3.api)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution myself, this question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52694180/13968392). You have to add `None` before the `After` parameter:

```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book("test.xlsx")

ws1 = wb.sheets['Sheet1']
ws3 = wb.sheets['Sheet3']

ws1.api.Move(None, After=ws3.api)
# Or: ws1.api.Move(Before=None, After=ws3.api)
```

Strictly speaking, the question seems to be more related to pywin32 than to xlwings, because apparently `.api`  accesses the underlying pywin32 objects, as described [here](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/missing_features.html).