# Assistance with Excel VBA Reference Cell to Move Sheet to new workbook and save

Tags: excel, vba

I have browsed this and other forums to create a code to accomplish this task. I have no previous VBA experience so please be gentle.

Essentially, what I would like to have happen is the user fills out the Excel form and clicks a button. The button will reference what was selected in cell K4 and then based off that selection, copy a hidden worksheet into a new workbook and then prompt the user to save.

The Code I am using is:

```
Private Sub RSM_Click()
    Dim newWkbk As Workbook
    Dim newWksht As Worksheet
    Dim wksht As Worksheet
    Dim test As String

    If StrComp(Me.Range("K4").Text, "INTERNAL USB", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        test = "RSM_InternalUSB"
    ElseIf StrComp(Me.Range("K4").Text, "INTERNAL 24 HR", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        test = "RSM_Internal24Hr"
    Else
        test = "RSM_External"
    End If


    For Each wksht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If wksht.Name = test Then
            wksht.Visible = xlSheetVisible
            Set newWksht = wksht.Copy
            newWksht.Name = "RSM Onboarding Guide"
            Set newWkbk = newWksht.Parent
        End If
    Next wksht

    Dim varResult As Variant
    Dim ActBook As Workbook

    'displays the save file dialog
    varResult = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:= _
             "Excel Files (*.xlsm), *.xlsm", Title:="RSM Guide", _
            InitialFileName:="\\Onboarding\")

    'checks to make sure the user hasn't canceled the dialog
    If varResult <> False Then
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=varResult
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

However I am getting a

> Compile error: Expected function or Variable

on the `Set newwksht = wksht.Copy` strand. It doesn't like the copy.

I don't even know if the save portion will work as I haven't been able to get past this

Comment: The `Worksheet.Copy` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.copy) should be helpful, specifically the second to last code snippet, which shows how to copy a worksheet to a new workbook and then save.

Comment: Have a look at the answers to this question : https://stackoverflow.com/q/30575923/4961700

Answer (score 0):

could try this:

```
If GetSheet(test, newWksht) Then
    With newWksht
        .Visible = xlSheetVisible
        .Copy ' this will make a copy of the referenced sheet in a newly created workbook
        ActiveSheet.Name = "new"
        .Visible = xlSheetHidden
    End With
    Dim varResult As Variant
   'displays the save file dialog
    varResult = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:= _
             "Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", Title:="RSM Guide", _
            InitialFileName:="\\Onboarding\")
    With ActiveWorkbook ' reference the newly created workbook, which is the "active" one
        'checks to make sure the user hasn't canceled the dialog
        If varResult <> False Then .SaveAs Filename:=varResult
    End With
End If
```

where it uses this `GetSheet()` "helper" function:

```
Function GetSheet(shtName As String, retSht As Worksheet) As Boolean
    Set retSht = Worksheets(shtName)
    GetSheet = Not retSht Is Nothing
End Function
```