# Copy worksheets from 1 workbook to another open workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the below code to move a worksheet from one open workbook to another open workbook but it's breaking on the last line of the code. From everything that I see online, it looks like this code should work.

```
Error MSG : (Run-time error '9') (Subscription out of range)

Sheets("Summary ML").Select

Workbooks.Open Filename:=outputfile
Windows(wb).Activate
Sheets("Summary ML").Select
Sheets("Summary ML").Copy After:=Workbooks("outputfile.xlsx").Sheets(2)
```

Comment: Does `Workbooks("outputfile.xlsx").Sheets(2)` exist? I am talking about i) the workbook itself and ii) the sheet with index 2

Comment: Yes, the workbook is being opened prior to the code where i try to copy over the new sheet. The workbook has 1 sheet currently in it when it's opened and I'm trying to copy a new sheet after the sheet that's already there.

Comment: If thwe workbook has 1 sheet only then `Sheets(2)` will run into an error

Comment: see how I did it, not saying it's the best though: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30605765/4961700

Comment: @DZIQ  , May I Ask you to leave me some feedbacks on the answer I proposed ? If it answers to your needs May I ask you to accept my answer :  [look here to see how to accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this :

```
Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").Worksheets.Copy Before:=Workbooks("Book2.xlsx").Sheets(1)
```

If you don't know the meaning of `sheet(1)` you can do `debug.print sheet(1).Name`

Kindest regards.