# Copy worksheets from a master workbook to active workbook

Tags: excel, vba

The following code works sometimes but not always. I have looked at similar examples, but I need to work in a particular way (copy all worksheets from Master to active workbook).

I am trying to copy the worksheets from a 'Master' workbook ("MasterWorkbook.xlsm" spreadsheet) into my active workbook (an .xlsx file). I am running the macro from my active workbook. I have the 'Master' workbook open as well.

```
Sub CopySheetsFromMaster()
  Dim ToWorkbook As Workbook
  Set ToWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Workbooks("MasterWorkbook.xlsm").Worksheets.Copy After:=ToWorkbook.Sheets(ToWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

The code stops running at Line 5 "Workbooks("MasterWorkbook.xlsm").Worksheets.Copy...". I get the following error message "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range".

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30575923/4961700

Comment: You've got `CopyToWorkbook` defined at the start but on line 5 you're using something called `ToWorkbook` ... `After:=ToWorkbook.Sheets(ToWorkbook.Sheets.Count)`

Comment: Thanks for picking up, while an error in what I copied and pasted here, it's not the source of the error in Excel. I have now fixed code snippet above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to open the workbook first. Use the [Workbooks.Open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open) method which opens a workbook.

```
Sub CopySheetsFromMaster()
  Dim ToWorkbook As Workbook
  Set ToWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
  Application.EnableEvents = False

  Application.Workbooks.Open("path_to_your_workbook").Worksheets.Copy After:=ToWorkbook.Sheets(ToWorkbook.Sheets.Count)

  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Also, it makes sense to check the parameters you pass to the [Worksheet.Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Worksheet.Copy) method. Try to remove the `After` parameter. If it works correctly, then you need to pay special attention to the parameter.