# How to copy a specific worksheet from different excel files and merge them into one?

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to the world of Excel VBA World, I am currently working on merging multiple worksheets from different .csv files (same folder) into one giant .csv file.

Previously, I have already ran a code (successfully) to select all the data I wanted to all the .csv files in that folder. But I can't seem to merge all the sheets from these files into one....

```
This is the successful code

Option Explicit

Sub LoopThroughFiles()
    Dim xFd As FileDialog
    Dim xFdItem As Variant
    Dim xFileName As String
    Set xFd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    If xFd.Show = -1 Then
        xFdItem = xFd.SelectedItems(1) & Application.PathSeparator
        xFileName = Dir(xFdItem & "*.csv*")
        Do While xFileName <> ""
            With Workbooks.Open(xFdItem & xFileName)
                'your code here
                OP10SelectCut
            End With
            xFileName = Dir
        Loop
    End If
End Sub


Sub OP10SelectCut()
'
' OP10SelectCut 巨集
'
'
Dim TotalRow As Integer

TotalRow = Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row
        
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlNotBetween, _
        Formula1:="=-0.02", Formula2:="=0.02"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$B$1:$B$" & TotalRow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB(255 _
        , 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
    Columns("B:C").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

```
This is the not working code
'合併多個Excel檔案
Sub GetSheets()
Path = "C:\Users\andrew-wu\Desktop\OP10TestBatch"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.csv*")
  Do While Filename <> "*.csv*"
  Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
  '只複製第一個Sheet
  If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count > 0 Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Copy _
        After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
  '每個Sheet都複製
  'For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    'Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
  'Next Sheet
  End If

     Workbooks(Filename).Close
     Filename = Dir()
  Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Have a look at how I moved sheets around, give it a vote if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30575923/4961700

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the reply! After reading the post and customized your solution to mine (as csv files), I have encountered errors regarding (subscript out of range)