# Import 8 workbooks in to one workbook with each having thier own sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have 8 workbooks all with one sheet and I'm trying to import them into one master workbook using VBA. This is the code I'm using, it's my first time using VBA.

```vb
Sub ImportStats()
    Dim WbDest As Workbook
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim myPath As String
    Dim strFileName As String

    myPath = ThisWorkbook.path & "\stats\"

    Set weDest = ThisWorkbook
    strFileName = Dir(myPath)
    Do Until strFileName = ""
        Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & "\" & strFileName)
        Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets(1)
        wsSource.Copy after:=WbDest.Worksheets("National2")
        wbSource.Close
        strFileName = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Lots on here about this - have a search but see this as an example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30575923/4961700

Comment: Think about what paths you are building.  Specifically for the Dir(myPath) and the ... .Open

Answer (score 0):

### Looping Through Files Using `Dir`

**Multiple Issues**

- `'***` is indicating modifications of your code.
- Although `Dir` would accept `ThisWorkbook.Path & "\stats\"`, `ThisWorkbook.Path & "\stats"` (without the trailing backslash) is sufficient, which will also prevent having a double backslash (wrong) when later building the path with `myPath & "\" & strFileName)` (indicated in chris neilsen's comment).
- `Set weDest = ThisWorkbook` contains a typo and should be `Set wbDest = ThisWorkbook`. Using `Option Explicit` at the beginning of each module, will force you to declare all variables and will 'find' these typos immediately.
- In the line `CurrentIndex = WbDest.Sheets("National2").Index`, we are defining the position of the sheet in the tabs. When using the `After` argument, then when we add a sheet its index will be by one (1) greater than the index of the specified sheet. When we add another one, its index should be by one (1) greater than the previous one (by two (2) greater than the index of the specified sheet)... hence: `CurrentIndex = CurrentIndex + 1`.
- With `SaveChanges:=False` in `wbSource.Close SaveChanges:=False` we are preventing `Excel` to show us a message (when the worksheet was somehow modified (recalculated)), to ask if the workbook should be saved before closing.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportStats()
    
    Dim WbDest As Workbook
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim myPath As String
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim CurrentIndex As Long '***

    myPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\stats" '***

    Set WbDest = ThisWorkbook '***
    CurrentIndex = WbDest.Sheets("National2").Index '***

    strFileName = Dir(myPath)

    Do Until strFileName = ""
        Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & "\" & strFileName)
        Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets(1)
        wsSource.Copy After:=WbDest.Sheets(CurrentIndex) '***
        wbSource.Close SaveChanges:=False '***
        CurrentIndex = CurentIndex + 1 ' ***
        strFileName = Dir()
    Loop

End Sub
```