# How to migrate many excel sheets to one master workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I commonly have several workbooks with individual sheets to migrate to a master workbook, think:

- Jan.xlsx
- Feb.xlsx
- Mar.xlxs
- ...
- Dec.xlsx

to a recap on a single sheet named 2020Recap.xlxm.  I'd like to build a macro to collect each worksheet and write to the recap workbook, I've started with the VBA script below.

I'm having trouble with the VBA below

I'd like to also add to the macro to use the filename as the sheet name.

```
Sub CopySheets()

Workbooks("C:\Test\Account AR Aging Patient.xlsx").Sheets("Account AR Aging Patient.xlsx").Copy _
  After:=Workbooks("c:\Test\MEBIllingOffice.xlsm").Sheets(Workbooks("c:\Test\MEBIllingOffice.xlsm").Sheets.Count)

Workbooks("C:\Test\Account AR Aging Payer.xlsx").Sheets("Account AR Aging Payer.xlsx").Copy _
    After:=Workbooks("c:\Test\MEBIllingOffice.xlsm").Sheets(Workbooks("c:\Test\MEBIllingOffice.xlsm").Sheets.Count)

Workbooks("C:\Test\AR History.xlsx").Sheets("AR History").Copy _
    After:=Workbooks("c:\Test\MEBIllingOffice.xlsm").Sheets(Workbooks("c:\Test\MEBIllingOffice.xlsm").Sheets.Count)

End Sub
```

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30575923/4961700 and vote for it if you find it useful.

Comment: What's the problem though?

Comment: I receive a runtime error 9 subscript out of range message

Comment: When do you get the error? which line?

Comment: On the very first line, it seems to be the file and directory name

Comment: I'm not fully confident I've started the code correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the workbook name in the sheet name.  Try:

```
Dim wb_source As Workbook
Dim wb_target As Workbook

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set wb_source = Workbooks.Open("C:\Test\Account AR Aging Patient.xlsx")
Set wb_target = Workbooks.Open("c:\Test\MEBIllingOffice.xlsm")

'assuming the sheet name is "Sheet1"
wb_source.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy after:=wb_target.Sheets(wb_target.Sheets.Count)
wb_source.Close

'next source.  note: sheet names must be unique within target
Set wb_source = Workbooks.Open("C:\Test\Account AR Aging Payer.xlsx")
wb_source.Sheets("Sheet2").Copy after:=wb_target.Sheets(wb_target.Sheets.Count)
wb_source.Close

wb_target.Save
wb_target.Close

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```