# Open many xlsx files and run a package that calculates a set of non parametric variables for each file

Tags: r, excel, loops, calculation

I need some help for my master thesis

I have a very large set of xlsx files and must calculate a series of indices for each file. I have the code for doing it one excel file at the time, but it would take many days to do it one by one. So does anyone nows how to open several excel files at the same time and do a loop for the calculation and putting all the indices in a matrix?
This is the code for one file at the time:

```
install.packages("nparACT")
```

```
library(nparACT)
```

(Import the data set manually of one file [I am new to R])

```
Nuevo <- data.frame(as.factor(P1_a_completo_Tmov$Datetime), P1_a_completo_Tmov$Dist)
```

(P1_a_completo_Tmov is the name of the file, example)

```
nparACT_base("Nuevo", SR=1/30)
```

(This last command gives me many options, what I need is the data.frame, so what I do now is to copy nparACT_base("Nuevo", SR=1/30) in the console and then I get the data frame)

Now I am stuck with a very inefficient time consuming way of working, but hope that one of you R experts can give me some light on how to speed the process. Thank you

Comment: Consider a loop, see this in vba: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30575923/4961700

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.