# How to paste data from a worksheet in a master workbook into up to 30 other workbooks using a loop?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy data from a master file and then paste it into workbooks already open on a loop.

It gets stuck at

```
If WS.Name = WB.Sheets("FX Rates") Then
```

```vb
Sub Update_Files()

Dim WB As Workbook
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim Master As Workbook

Set Master = ThisWorkbook

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FX").Range("A1:I148").Select
Selection.Copy

For Each WB In Application.Workbooks
    If WB.Name <> "Master File.xlsb" Then
        If WS.Name = WB.Sheets("FX Rates") Then
            'Paste FX data from Master
            Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlpastevalues
        End If
    End If
Next WB
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing a loop for worksheets?

Comment: You don't define `ws` anywhere.

Comment: And anyway it should be `If WS.Name = "FX Rates"`.

Comment: Have a look at this, and give it a vote: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30575923/4961700

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, looks like you're missing a loop for your worksheets. Currently, you're only looping through your workbooks, not worksheets.

Added a loop to address this. Code loops through each open workbook, checks name. `If Name <> "Master File.xlsb"`, then it continues to the next loop.
This second loop iterates over each worksheet in current workbook, and checks if it's name equals `"FX Rates"`, if it does, it pastes copied selection and continues the loop.

There are however much more VBA-ish way to achieve the same thing, but this answers your question. It compiles and runs just fine.

```
Sub Update_Files()
    
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim Master As Workbook
    
    Set Master = ThisWorkbook
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FX").Range("A1:I148").Select
    Selection.Copy

    For Each WB In Application.Workbooks
        If WB.Name <> "Master File.xlsb" Then
            For Each WS In WB.Worksheets
                If WS.Name = "FX Rates" Then
                    'Paste FX data from Master
                    WS.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                End If
            Next WS
        End If
    Next WB

End Sub
```

Comment: Also, make sure that your workbook is actually named with extension. I've found that it usually is not...

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Just had to tweak something due to formatting and is all working now.