# Copy data from multiple sheets into single sheet

Tags: excel, typescript, office365, office-scripts, ms-office-script

I'm trying to copy the excel multiple worksheets data into single worksheet using office scripts.can anyone tell how to do it?

I tried getting first range of the sheets after loop through the sheets but it's not working. I'm new to this so please help

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please show us a [minimal reproducible example for your question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: See this as a source of ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30575923/4961700