# How to Retrieve Data from Another Workbook in a Function

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm an absolute beginner in VBA and I would need some advice. I have two workbooks (Wb1 and Wb2).

and I need to create a VBA function that, based on the provided path to an external file, sheet names, and cell, returns its value. Wb1 is read-only. In my Wb2, I have created a module where I have written a function, the code of which is:

```
Function get_ExtVal(file As String, sheet As String, cell As String) As Variant

Dim Wb1 As Workbook

Dim value As Variant

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Input the path to the file

Set Wb1 = Workbooks.Open(file, ReadOnly:=True)

'This get some cell values.

value = Wb1.Sheets(sheet).Range(cell).value

'Close the workbook

Wb1.Close SaveChanges:=False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'Value out

get_ExtVal = value

End Function
```

But when I insert the called function into a cell in my Wb2:

```
 =IF(get_ExtVal("X:\Folder1\2024\Folder2\[Wb1.xlsx]"; "Sheet1"; &Zdroje!$A56&"13") > 0; get_ExtVal("X:\Folder1\2024\Folder2\[Wb1.xlsx]"; "Sheet1"; &Zdroje!$A56&"218"); "")
```

The function returns an error #VALUE!

I have checked the paths, cell numbers, and column numbers countless times to make sure they are correct. Everything is correct. What else could be wrong? I also tried adding a variable extSheet, and after the instruction

```
Set Wb1 = Workbooks.Open...
```

I added

```
 Set extSheet = Wb1.Sheets(sheet)
```

but it practically didn't help (if I understand correctly, it's the same as I have in the code above).

Could the issue be that Wb1 doesn't have macro support? I know it's probably silly, but I'm running out of ideas.

I also tried deleting the concatenation of the source cell from Wb2 and replaced it with:

```
&Zdroje!$A56&"13" ---> AJ13
```

That also had no effect, so the error is probably not in this notation.

I just need, in case the cell in WB1.Sheet1.AJ13 is bigger then 0, to transfer the result from WB1.Sheet1.AJ218 to cell with this function in Wb2.Sheet2. (This will be repeated for about 200 different cells in various rows and columns.)

Comment: A function called from a worksheet cannot open a file.

Comment: @Scott Cramer: I tweaked  the code from [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/best-way-to-get-data-from-a-closed-workbook.1170613/post-5690481) and you can retrieve a value from a closed workbook

Comment: See this, 6 master files used to send data to many files... : https://stackoverflow.com/q/30575923/4961700

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comment I tweaked the code from [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/best-way-to-get-data-from-a-closed-workbook.1170613/#post-5690481) a bit

The following function `getData` will return single cells or even ranges from a closed Excel workbook. The function `cleanArray` is need to replace database `Null` with a `vbNullChar`. Otherwise the function would return `#VALUE` when used as user defined function

```
    Option Explicit
    
    Public Function GetData(SourceFile As Variant, SourceSheet As String, _
        SourceRange As String)
    
        Dim rsCon As Object, rsData As Object, szConnect As String, szSQL As String
    
        If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
            szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No"";"
        Else
            szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=No"";"
        End If
    
    
        If SourceSheet = "" Then
            ' workbook level name
            szSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & SourceRange$ & ";"
        Else
            ' worksheet level name or range
            szSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & SourceSheet$ & "$" & SourceRange$ & "];"
        End If
    
        On Error GoTo SomethingWrong
    
        Set rsCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        Set rsData = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    
        rsCon.Open szConnect
        rsData.Open szSQL, rsCon, 0, 1, 1
        
        If Not rsData.EOF Then            
            GetData = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(cleanArray(rsData.GetRows))
        End If
        
        rsData.Close: Set rsData = Nothing
        rsCon.Close: Set rsCon = Nothing
        
        Exit Function
    
SomethingWrong:
    ' write basic information in the immediate window
    ' in case of an error
    Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    End Function

    ' Needed to replace database Null
    Function cleanArray(vData As Variant) As Variant
        Dim i As Long, j As Long
        For i = LBound(vData, 1) To UBound(vData, 1)
            For j = LBound(vData, 2) To UBound(vData, 2)
                If IsNull(vData(i, j)) Then vData(i, j) = vbNullChar
            Next j
        Next i
        cleanArray = vData
    End Function
```

You can now put the following formulas in your worksheet

```
    = GetData("D:\TMP\a.xlsx", "Sheet1", "E4:E4")
    'This will return the value from E4 in Sheet1

     = GetData("D:\TMP\a.xlsx", "Sheet1", "A1:B2")
   'This will return the values of the range A1:B2 in Sheet1

    = GetData("D:\TMP\a.xlsx", "Sheet1", "")
    'This will return the values in Sheet1
```

There might be some pitfalls. I did not check what happens in case of error values in the source sheet. I did not check the case you enter a diagram sheet and so on.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice initially. I tried your code, and this function always returns a value of 0. Initially, I tried using just the cell address (not a range - even if I try just =[a.xlsx]Sheet1!E4:E4 - it still returns just 0), but it's still not working.

Comment: Are you saying that you use `a.xlsx` when you call the function? You have to use YOUR filename, of course, and the sheetname of YOUR sheet in question. I thought that is obvious.

Comment: Of course I used my name and location. I'm writing a.xlsx here only because you have used this name in the code so I thought it would be better for communication. :-D Apparently not.

Comment: I am sorry, then I got you wrong :-(  The examples I provided worked for me. So, first parameter is the complete filename, second parameter is the sheetname, third parameter is the range. So, trying to use `=[a.xlsx]Sheet1!E4:E4` cannot work at all.

Comment: I tested the above function with wrongly written filename resp. sheetname then the result will be a 0. So, I guess, you made a spelling error in one of the parameters

Comment: I have it written like this:  `=GetData("X:\9_Reporting\2024\OEE\BMW_Saleri_OEE_2024.xlsx"; "B38_48TÜ1_line1"; "AJ218:AJ218")` The addresses and the sheet name are copied directly from Excel, so there shouldn't be an error in that. Your function code, I copied it exactly as you have it. Is there something in VBA that I must change?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Did you do a Debug/Compile? That is just to make sure that everything was copied fine.

Comment: Are you sure you have any data in AJ218?

Comment: I edited the answer and added some code. If there's an error you could check in the immediate window for an error message.

Comment: I may have found the problem why it's not doing anything. The Immediate window is reporting error 429: ActiveX component can't create object. I assume it might be related. Unfortunately, I'll have to consult with our IT department about that. I don't have the permissions.

Comment: Ah, ok, then you are probably out of luck because the error means that `Set rsCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")` failed and that means that ADODB is not installed on your computer. PS Do you have a Mac?

Comment: No i haven't Mac. Unfortunately IT doesn't want to install ADODB... moreover this workbook will be used by more people so everyone would have to have it installed. So I finally created a function that opens all source workbooks in read-only mode and thanks to the indirect function I can access the data (unfortunately, after closing the source workbooks the data disappears and the function declares an error - but I don't think this can be solved. Thanks for the advice though.