# Save Excel Sheet to a folder as PDF with filename based on cell value + Current Month name

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I work on a sheet and I need to save it as PDF to my folder ("D:\NEWGIZA") so I recorded a simple macro linked to a control button to do that and it ok so far - but what I don't know how to do is that I want to make the file name of saved PDF to be the same as cell "M5"+ the current month name (in Arabic). for example like that name (21 NEW 447 يناير) which = in english (21 NEW 447 January) please note that "M5"value is not fixed but changes every time and it doesnt include the month text but only like (21 NEW 447)
this is my simple code

```
Sub PDF()
'
' PDF Macro
' Save As PDF
'

'
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "D:\NEWGIZA\Guards.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:= _
        True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: See this as an example of building names: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30575923/4961700

Comment: It's completely different issue

Comment: So changing the filename using a loop does not help...

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not professional with Codes - if you have a complete answer I appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Export To PDF (Locale Issue)

```vb
Sub ExportToPDF()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim Filename As String: Filename = "D:\NEWGIZA\" & ws.Range("M5").Value _
        & " " & Application.Text(Month(Date), "[$-401]mmmm") & ".pdf"
 
    ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=Filename, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Can I make the pdf file go to another sub folder based on a cell value?

Comment: Sure. Ask another question with the details and someone will surely answer. You can post a link to it in your comments, which will alert everyone following this post.

Comment: ok, doing that but i cannot add your code to my question giving me error (Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or) inspite i added ```` beofre the code

Comment: Don't worry, just copy/paste the code (if necessary, from your `Visual Basic Editor`) into your question and someone will format it.