Copy a Sheet from workbook to another workbook and modify all references of ActiveX controls, Shapes and Charts to the destination workbook
Suppose I have two workbooks (workbook1 and workbook2), I need to copy a sheet from workbook1 to workbook 2.
The name of the copied sheet e.g. “Board” has (ActiveX Controls) that have references to subroutines with macros assigned to it,
also has shapes like (Rounded Rectangle , Octagon) and Pictures that have references to either a cell value or subroutines with macros assigned to it,
also the copied sheet has Charts that have references to range of cells.
The problem with copied sheet is that all the subroutines and shapes
formula are still referenced to the source workbook (workbook1).
Note: (all referenced sheets name and all called procedures exists in the workbook where the sheet has been copied to).
So I need to modify the copied sheet to make all the references of subroutines and shapes formula (workbook 2).
I have used the below macro and it has success only with coping the sheet and modify (ActiveX Controls) subroutines with macros assigned. 
But with other shapes (Rounded Rectangle, Octagon,..etc) I have got

Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method

at this line If shp.Formula <> "" Then
And the code to change charts has no effect (without errors raised).
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Sub Copy_Sheet_to_another_Workbook()           'Assumes this code is found in Workbook1 (ThisWorkbook)
    
    Dim srcWs As Worksheet
    Dim dstWb As Workbook
    Dim dstWs As Worksheet
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim srcWbName As String
    Dim dstWbName As String
    
    With Application
      .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
      .ScreenUpdating = False
      .EnableEvents = False
      .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With
    
    Set srcWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Board")                             'name of the sheet to be copy
    Set dstWb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Workbook2.xlsb")    'destination Workbook
    srcWs.Copy Before:=dstWb.Sheets(1)
    Set dstWs = dstWb.Sheets(2)
    
    srcWbName = ThisWorkbook.name
    dstWbName = dstWb.name
      
'Update VBA references to macros/subroutines in shapes with macros assigned
   For Each shp In dstWs.Shapes
        If shp.OnAction <> "" Then
            If InStr(1, shp.OnAction, srcWbName, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                shp.OnAction = Replace(shp.OnAction, srcWbName, dstWbName)
            End If
        End If
    Next shp

'Update shapes with cell references in the formula
    For Each shp In dstWs.Shapes
        If shp.Formula <> "" Then
            If InStr(1, shp.Formula, srcWbName, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                shp.Formula = Replace(shp.Formula, srcWbName & "!", dstWbName & "!")
            End If
        End If
    Next shp

'Update chart references
    For Each chartObj In dstWs.ChartObjects
        With chartObj.Chart
            Dim srs As Series
            For Each srs In .SeriesCollection
                If InStr(1, srs.Formula, srcWbName, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    srs.Formula = Replace(srs.Formula, srcWbName & "!", dstWbName & "!")
                End If
            Next srs
        End With
    Next chartObj

    dstWb.Activate
    With Application
      .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
      .ScreenUpdating = True
      .EnableEvents = True
      .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
    
End Sub

Update1 - it seems that I have to select each shape and then check for its formula and modify it accordingly, 
and because not every shape has a formula, so I have to use an error handling.
the negative of this approach that it is still not working with Pictures formula and also does not work with any grouped shapes.
'Update shape formulas by selecting each shape (for shapes with cell references)
    For Each shp In dstWs.Shapes
      On Error Resume Next             'Ignore errors for shapes without a formula
       shp.Select
        If Selection.Formula <> "" Then
            If InStr(1, Selection.Formula, "[" & srcWbName & "]", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                Selection.Formula = Replace(Selection.Formula, "[" & srcWbName & "]", "")
            End If
        End If
      On Error GoTo 0                  'Reset error handling
    Next shp


Have a look at the answers here, as I moved many sheets: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30575923/4961700

@Solar Mike , the problem is not with the coping process, But with the references e.g If I clicked a shape on the copied sheet then I found that workbook1 has been reopened

Then remove the = from the references, which make it text, before you copy then replace the =. A trick I have explained on here before.

Should we understand that all referenced sheets name and all called procedures exists in the workbook where the sheet has been copied to? Or it is needed to identify the called subs and copy them, too? How did you make a shape referencing a cell?

@FaneDure , yes your understand is correct about (all referenced sheets name and all called procedures exists in the workbook where the sheet has been copied to). I mean by (shape referencing a cell) that the text of the shape = Cell.value (But also it happens I am using a normal shape to execute a procedure)

@Solar Mike , suppose I have 100 shapes on the sheet , Do you think it is considered a programming skill to manually select each shape and then remove the equal sign = and later readd again on the copied sheet!

I selected all the cells and used the edit find / replace tool, but not sure about shapes. You can find out.

You wrongly spelled my user name and I was not been announced... You can create a function able identify the shapes having formulas for their text and place the shape name and formula text in an array, then use it to change back. For formulae you can follow the @Solar Mike suggestion and you can replace the "=" formula character automatically only in SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas). This cannot be done at once because it does not work in discontinuous ranges... Then, you should proceed in the reverse order fot initial sheet and copied one, too.

What do you mean by "it does not work with grouped shapes"? Don't you try changing the formula of a group item? If so, you have to firstly determine if the shape is a group, then iterate between the group members and proceed exactly as I do it in my answer example.

Did you try just to change the link like
  YourTargetBook.ChangeLink Name:="YourSourceBook.xlsm", NewName:="YourTargetBook.xlsm", Type:= _
        xlExcelLinks

To change them all at once?
It is not easy to guess what happens in your books.
But this will change the Macro in my experiment.

It works Brilliantly. I must confess that I initially did not thought it will fulfil all my needs. After testing, I found it works correctly with every elements on the destination workbook e.g. (shapes ,grouped shapes ,Pictures, charts,...etc.) even (cells formulas) have been relinked to the destination workbook.

Please, try the next testing subs.

The first one tries showing how to keep the same formula using Solar Mike's suggestion:

Sub ModifyFormulaMemorizeRange()
  Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet, rngFormula As Range, rngFormula1 As Range, cel As Range
  Set wsSource = ActiveSheet
  
  Set rngFormula = wsSource.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
  For Each cel In rngFormula.Cells
    cel.Formula = VBA.Replace(cel.Formula, "=", "xyz#@") 'use a string not probable to be found between existing...
  Next cel
  Stop 'please, check the transformed formulas
  
  'copy the sheet after the active one:
  wsSource.Copy after:=wsSource
   Stop 'please, see the newly copied sheet
   
  Set wsDest = wsSource.Next
  Set rngFormula1 = wsDest.Range(rngFormula.Address)

  For Each cel In rngFormula.Cells
    cel.Formula = VBA.Replace(cel.Formula, "xyz#@", "=")
  Next cel
  wsSource.Calculate
  Stop 'see the original sheet restored formulas...
  
  'Change back formulas in the copied cells
  For Each cel In rngFormula1.Cells
    cel.Formula = VBA.Replace(cel.Formula, "xyz#@", "=")
  Next cel
  wsDest.Calculate
  Stop 'check the copied cells formulas...
End Sub


The next one tries explaining how changing the shapes formulas if the case:

Sub MemorizeShapesTextFormula()
  Dim sh As Shape, ws As Worksheet, k As Long
  
  Set ws = ActiveSheet
  ReDim arrShFormula(ws.Shapes.Count)
  For Each sh In ws.Shapes
    If CBool(sh.TextFrame2.HasText) Then
        sh.Select
        With Selection
            If isLinkedCell(.Formula, .Text) Then
                arrShFormula(k) = sh.Name & "|=" & .Formula: k = k + 1
            End If
        End With
    End If
  Next sh
  If k > 0 Then ReDim Preserve arrShFormula(k - 1)
  Debug.Print Join(arrShFormula, " ") 'just to see what has been memorized
  
End Sub

Function isLinkedCell(cellAddress As String, shText As String) As Boolean
  On Error Resume Next
   If Range(cellAddress).Value = shText Then isLinkedCell = True
  On Error GoTo 0
End Function

1.b. How using the above loaded array to change the formulas of copied shapes:
Sub AdaptShapesTextFormulas()
  Dim wsSource As Worksheet, sh As Shape, i As Long
  
  Set wsSource = ActiveSheet.Next 'mentain selected the sheet where the array has been loaded...
  For i = 0 To UBound(arrShFormula)
    wsSource.Shapes(Split(arrShFormula(i), "|")(0)).Select
    Selection.Formula = Split(arrShFormula(i), "|")(1)
  Next i
  
End Sub

Edited:
For dealing with grouped shapes, please use the next testing sub:
Sub testGroupMembersFormula()
 Dim sh As Shape, i As Long
 
 For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If sh.Type = msoGroup Then
        For i = 1 To sh.GroupItems.Count
            Debug.Print sh.GroupItems(i).Name
             sh.GroupItems(i).Select
             Debug.Print Selection.Formula
        Next i
    End If
 Next sh
End Sub


Indeed handling of pure formulas (which exists in a cell) is the easiest part and so I did not mention on my question, I have used the same trick but without using any kind of loop. srcWs.UsedRange.Replace What:="=", Replacement:="XYZ@#", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False and it works correctly even in discontinuous range.

Concerning handling of (shapes formulas) , I have got (Compile error: Type mismatch) at this line wsSource.Shapes(Split(arrShFormula, "|")(0)).Select. Anyhow I managed to partially solving this part (kindly see Update1 on my question).

@Peace In discontinuous ranges it does not raise an error, but makes replacements only in the first discontinuous range area, or will make the same replacement in all cells. But UsedRange cannot be discontinuous... I used the discontinuous range thinking that used range may be huge and iterating through a smaller range will be. And I did not test the second sub, which obviously has a principle mistake. It should be  arrShFormula(i) instead of arrShFormula. I will correct it now. Corrected.

@Peace I could see some minutes your question edited part and I edited my answer placing an example of procedure able to deal with shapes being part of a group.

I am afraid to say I don't know exactly how to apply your answers?

FYI formulas in shapes are exposed via the Drawingobject property  - for example Activesheet.Shapes(1).DrawingObject.Formula or Activesheet.Shapes(1).GroupItems(1).DrawingObject.Formula  Returns an empty string if there's no formula

@Tim Williams Thanks! I had no idea about the issue. I never needed it. I've just found selection by testing...

Just to add to the mix because it seemed like an interesting (if slightly obscure) problem.
Just focusing on dealing with shapes (updating formulas and OnAction)
Sub TestCopy()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wbNew As Workbook
    
    Set ws = Sheet1                       'the source sheet
    Set wbNew = Workbooks("Book6")        'copying to this wb
    ws.Copy before:=wbNew.Worksheets(1)
    
    SyncShapes ws, wbNew.Worksheets(1)

End Sub

Sub SyncShapes(wsSource As Worksheet, wsCopy As Worksheet)
    Dim shp As Shape, f As String
    Dim sourceShapes As Collection, copyShapes As Collection
    Dim shpMatch As Shape, actn As String, newActn As String, arr
 
    Set sourceShapes = WorksheetShapes(wsSource) 'all shapes on original sheet
    Set copyShapes = WorksheetShapes(wsCopy)     'all shapes on sheet copy
    
    For Each shp In copyShapes   'loop over all shapes  on the sheet copy
        Set shpMatch = ShapeMatch(shp, sourceShapes) 'try to find a matching shape...
        If Not shpMatch Is Nothing Then
            
            Debug.Print "Matched", shp.Name, shpMatch.Name
            
            f = shpMatch.DrawingObject.Formula 'check for formula
            If Len(f) > 0 Then                 'shape has a formula?
                shp.DrawingObject.Formula = f  'sync the formula
                SyncTextProps shpMatch, shp    'reset text properties
            End If
            
            actn = shpMatch.OnAction
            If Len(actn) > 0 Then 'shape has a linked macro?
                arr = Split(actn, "!")
                newActn = "'" & wsCopy.Parent.Name & "'!" & arr(1)
                shp.OnAction = newActn
                Debug.Print "OnAction", actn, newActn
            End If
        Else
            'no match found: maybe flag a problem here....
            Debug.Print "No match for", shp.Name
        End If
    Next shp
End Sub

'All worksheet shapes as a flattened collection
'   (excluding chartobjects)
Function WorksheetShapes(ws As Worksheet) As Collection
    Dim shp As Shape, subShp As Shape
    Set WorksheetShapes = New Collection
    For Each shp In ws.Shapes 'all top-level shapes
        If shp.Type <> msoChart Then 'exclude charts
            If shp.Type = msoGroup Then
                For Each subShp In shp.GroupItems
                    'charts can be grouped....
                    If shp.Type <> msoChart Then WorksheetShapes.Add subShp
                Next subShp
            Else
                WorksheetShapes.Add shp
            End If
        End If
    Next shp
End Function

'Try to match shape `shp` to another item in collection `col`,
'  based on Top+Left properties (assumes only one possible match)
'  Needs a bit of leeway since copied sheet shapes aren't always
'    in exactly the same position....
Function ShapeMatch(shp As Shape, col As Collection) As Shape
    Dim s As Shape
    'Debug.Print "---Matching shape Top=" & shp.Top & " Left = " & shp.Left
    For Each s In col
        'Debug.Print , s.Top, s.Left
        If Abs(s.Top - shp.Top) < 2 And Abs(s.Left - shp.Left) < 2 Then
            Set ShapeMatch = s
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next s
End Function

'sync up text properties in `shpDest` using values from `shpSrc`
Sub SyncTextProps(shpSrc As Shape, shpDest As Shape)
    Dim el, v
    For Each el In Array("Size", "Name", "Bold", "Italic", "UnderlineStyle")
        v = CallByName(shpSrc.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font, el, VbGet)
        CallByName shpDest.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font, el, VbLet, v
    Next el
    shpDest.TextFrame.Characters.Font.Color = shpSrc.TextFrame.Characters.Font.Color
End Sub


I have got (Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method) at this line f = shpMatch.DrawingObject.Formula after debugging I found shp.Name= Chart 7 I have used On Error Resume Next ( I know it is not recommended), the result is success with single shapes and OnAction macros , But not works with any shape found on a group.

Do you have OnAction assigned to groups, or just to single shapes?

Updated WorksheetShapes to exclude charts

This would be easier if you're able to share a sample workbook with a specific example worksheet showing the type of scenario you want to be able to handle (ie. all things that need to be handled shape-wise)

this seems to be a little bit confusing.
The shape object does not have a property formula also you can add a formula to a shape and it will be recognized as a shape.
But these kind of shapes are special objects e.g. ovals -> oval
Let's say you insert an oval (I will uses this as example for all possible shapes which can have a formula) an give it a formula. It will be found as a shape but would not present a formula property. Even if you look for objects.
The problem could be, that an oval is a hidden element, just have a look in the object explorer and show the hidden elements.
I guess you have to know, which special types of shapes you use to iterate through them
Sub JustToShow()
Dim ov As Oval
For Each ov In ActiveSheet.Ovals
Debug.Print ov.Formula
Next ov
End Sub

But i think, that this kind of using shapes with formulas are anyway more then critical. They may be highliy volatile.
